# Determining the culture of reporting services server

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using the web service “ReportingService2005.asmx” to set parameters of reports and linked reports. Here for I call the method “SetReportParameters(NewItemPath, Parameters)”. This works great until I try to set a parameter of the type DateTime. Here I get a format exception. The reason for this is that the value is a formatted string where the format does not fit. For example I have a parameter coming from a German Server (“31.1.2010 00:00:00”) and try to set it on an English Server (“12/31/2010 12:00 AM”).
To solve this problem I need to know the culture that the server is using so I can format the string before I call the method. Is it possible to get the culture/language of the server through the web service “ReportingService2005.asmx”?
I could also imagine that there are other ways to solve this problem, but haven’t find anything so fare. Are there other ways to take care of the internationalization of parameters using the web service? Has anyone other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the odbc format

2010-10-15 08:56.

If it doesn't work at all, you can do it "manually", i mean by doing a convert into sql code.

Comment: Also for doing it manually I first need to know from what source format to what target format I need to convert. That is my problem.

Comment: How do you access the webServices ? If it's in ASP.Net you should access with the Session class maybe.